# Python Selenium web scraping with concurrent futures

Tags: python, selenium, python-multithreading

I'm writing a script which will scrape data from multiple articles from the same website. I'd like to use threading to make the whole process faster. 
I've been using the following code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def scraping(url):
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--incognito")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
    driver.get(url)
    # elements will be added to dictionary 'dic'
    dic = {}
    ##########################################
    # Selecting elements to scrape goes here #
    ##########################################
    driver.quit()
    return dic

# loading the URLS and adding them to a list called 'lines'
with open ('URLS', 'rb') as fp:
    lines = pickle.load(fp)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 2) as executor:

    start = time.time()
    futures = { executor.submit(scraping, url): url for url in lines }
    data = []
    for result in as_completed(futures):
        try:
            data.append(result.result())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    end = time.time()
    print("Time Taken: {:.6f}s".format(end-start))
```

However, each time the function 'scraping' gets called it creates a new instance of the browser, so at each iteration I have 2 new windows. My goal is to make 2 windows that will stay open and continue scraping the links. Anyone got an idea how to do this?

Comment: futures = .. makes different objects each time. I think using Threading inside scraping function will work. After driver.get(url) for example.

Comment: @shimo Thanks for the reply. I'll try to follow your advice and will update if I'm successful.

Comment: Just have the scraping function pop urls off a queue and add the result to a global array